# What is bigger, $\liminf $ or $\inf ( \liminf )$

Tags: limsup-and-liminf

Let $E$ be a linear normed vector space, $f$ a functional $f : E \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ and $ S = \{g \in E : \|g\| = 1\} \subset E$.

Fix $x \in E$. I need to prove that $$\liminf_{g \in S,  \ \alpha \rightarrow +0 } \frac{f(x+\alpha g)-f(x)}{\alpha} \leq \inf_{g \in S} (\liminf_{\alpha  \rightarrow +0}\frac{f(x+\alpha g)-f(x)}{\alpha}) $$ I found this fact in my lecture notes and I have no idea of what's going on.

Comment: Are $E$ and $R$ subsets of the real numbers?

Comment: @bburGsamohT i added some information

Comment: How do you define $\liminf_{g \in S, \alpha \to +0}$? Namely, how do you treat the dependency on $g$ in the LHS?

Comment: @A.P.
I am not sure, I saw this construction first time. That is the question, too. I saw $\liminf $ only with one argument before